# RxSwift onNext not calling scan

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex, rx-cocoa

I am trying to create a `UICollectionView`, so that I can add and delete items from it's data source as a Driver. I have a viewModel below

```
import Photos
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

class GroupedAssetsViewModel {
enum ItemAction {
    case add(item: PHAssetGroup)
    case remove(indexPaths: [IndexPath])
}

let assets: Driver<[GroupedAssetSectionModel]>
let actions = PublishSubject<ItemAction>()
private let deletionService: AssetDeletionService = AssetDeletionServiceImpl()

init() {
    assets = actions
        .debug()
        .scan(into: []) { [deletionService] items, action in
            switch action {
            case .add(let item):
                let model = GroupedAssetSectionModel()
                items.append(GroupedAssetSectionModel(original: model, items: item.assets))
            case .remove(let indexPaths):
                var assets = [PHAsset]()
                for indexPath in indexPaths {
                    items[indexPath.section].items.remove(at: indexPath.item)
                    assets.append(items[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row])
                }
                deletionService.delete(assets: assets)
            }
        }
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
}

func setup(with assetArray: [PHAssetGroup] = [PHAssetGroup]()) {
    for group in assetArray {
        actions.onNext(.add(item: group))
    }
}
```

}

but `.scan` closure is never being called, even though `actions.onNext` is being called in `setup`, therefore Driver's value is always empty.

It seems like I am getting some core concepts wrong, what might be the problem here?

Comment: Are you subscribing to `assets` somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, the subscription was after the setup and I was getting no result

Comment: That tells me that your _real_ problem is that you are using a `PublishSubject` for `actions`. your view model should not have any Subjects in it at all. It should be Observables in, Observables out.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have
`actions.onNext(.add(item: group))` doesn't mean this sequence has started. You are publishing events to a subject that hasn't started. You must have a subscriber somewhere first for `assets`. Then only `scan` will get executed. Because observables are pull driven sequences. There must be a subscriber to even make them start.